# Change iPhone App Status Bar Properties

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, statusbar

My app will be full screen, but I am having trouble finding the document that explains how to change the status bar properties.

How can I change the status bar properties?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO]` should hide the status bar. Is that what you want?

edit: You could also add the following to `Info.plist`:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true />
```

Comment: a couple comments:  I seem to recall you can set these setting in Info.plist?  Also, I am very new to Objective-C and the iPhone frameworks, so I am not sure where to put the line above, in applicationDidFinishLaunching?

Comment: Not totally sure, but I imagine applicationDidFinishLaunching would be as good a place as any.

Comment: In my case, using setStatusBarHidden in applicationDidFinishLaunching still allowed the status bar to show for a second or two during loading.  Adding it to the plist file instead solved that and it does not show at all.

Comment: Update: -setStatusBarHidden: animated: is deprecated now.  You should drop the 'animated:' and just use
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]

Comment: This method has been deprecated as of iOS4

Answer (score 3):

The status bar APIs are part of the UIApplication class. Start there.

Answer (score 1):

Using Snow Leopard and the XCode 3.2, you simply edit the Apps Info.plist.

Add 2 rows:

Right click the open plist and add a row and select "Status bar is initially hidden" from the drop down list.
Check the checkbox it provides in the column to the right.

Add another row and select "Status Bar Style" from the drop down list.
In the column to the right type in UIStatusBarHidden

That works for me. I haven't experimented yet with changing the status bar view state at runtime though, say for example if the battery gets low.

And I'm not entirely sure that both values are needed if you add the second row's value.

// :)

Comment: Setting status bar style to 'none' in the drop down list still doesn't hide it. I think it can only be done via code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the old way has been deprecated:

```
// Old, Deprecated
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

The iOS 3.2+ way is

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

The animation options are:

```
UIStatusBarAnimationNone  // No animation is applied
UIStatusBarAnimationFade  // The status bar fades in and out
UIStatusBarAnimationSlide // The status bar slides in or out
```

And you can still do it the iOS 2.0+ way, with no animation:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```